# Big Query View -> PowerBI not reading column names correctly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This is the view/output from bigquery with the following view.

```
SELECT
    * EXCEPT (_resource_row_id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY meta.lastUpdated DESC) as _resource_row_id,
    *
    FROM `cie-uwsem-hub.cie_uwsem_semi_uat.HealthcareService` AS p
) AS p
WHERE
  p._resource_row_id=1
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(p.meta.tag)
  WHERE
    code = 'DELETE')
```

[image: bigquery output]

When it loads into powerbi it the unnest shows as:

[image: powerbi output]

I believe the problem is sourced from the schema, as powerbi can't read meta.secruity.system as it's own column.

[image: big_query_schema]

Would anyone know how to reference the nested columns as an seperate alias for powerbi to read properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented since 2018](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/BigQuery-Connector-repeated-records-type-not-supported/idi-p/337881) as a problem, and likely won't get fixed on PowerBI side.

You need to adjust your query and dereference the record attributes as normal columns. For this you need to use UNNEST, and you will have a row expansion so single rows turn into multiple rows.